# android:id what is the plus sign for

Tags: android

The document says "@[+]id/myid" as the definition for android:id, from the notation it indicates that the plus is optional. But nowhere can I find a definition of what the plus sign means or not supplying it would mean.

What does it mean and why is it there?

Comment: Related post - [Difference between “@id/” and “@+id/” in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5025910/465053)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> @+id/foo means you are creating an id named foo in the namespace of
>   your application. You can refer to it using @id/foo. @android:id/foo
>   means you are referring to an id defined in the android namespace.
>   This namespace is the namespace of the framework. In this case, you
>   need to use @android:id/list and @android:id/empty because these are
>   the id the framework expects to find (the framework knows only about
>   the ids in the android namespace.)

Taken from one of the ["Android Developer | Google Groups"](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dc8023b221351aa7?pli=1) discussions.

Answer (score 21):

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) says,

> The plus-symbol (+) means that this is
>   a new resource name that must be
>   created and added to our resources (in
>   the R.java file).  There are a number
>   of other ID resources that are offered
>   by the Android framework. When
>   referencing an Android resource ID,
>   you do not need the plus-symbol, but
>   must add the android package
>   namespace, like so:

```
android:id="@android:id/empty"
```