# IDs in Android layout XML with and without "+"

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “@id/” and  “@+id/” in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)

When you create a layout XML file for Android applications, you usually declare the ID of each layout element as:

```
@+id/elementID
```

Don't you? I guess the "+" means that this element's ID is just created and therefore you need the plus, right?

But what do you have to do when you refer to a layout element before it is created? Do you refer to it with "+" and then create it without "+"? Simply put, is the following code correct (in a RelativeLayout container)?

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/helpButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/moreButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@id/moreButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Comment: yes when you give the reference of predefined layout or view you use with out + like relative layout rightOf/leeftOF like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess the "+" means that this element's ID is just created and therefore you need the plus, right?

Yes.

> Do you refer to it with "+" and then create it without "+"?

Yes. The *first occurrence of the ID* gets the `+`. Second and subsequent occurrences can leave it off.

> Simply put, is the following code correct (in a RelativeLayout container)?

Well, your `ImageButtons` are missing images... :-)

That being said, your use of the `+` sign there seems fine.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I thought. Of course, my image buttons have images, but I left them off. Can you refer to any sources that prove this? (Because others think different about this, see the other answer.)

Comment: @MarcoW.: Well, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id, for starters. Also, see the examples of `RelativeLayout` on the Android developer site. This really only comes into play with `RelativeLayout` -- other containers do not use references to widget resources.

Comment: Can't really find any proof in the Android docs (see http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) but thanks, anyway!