# What is the difference between android:id="@+id/btnSet" and android:id="@id/btnSet"?

Tags: android, xml

can any body explain me what What is the difference between 
`android:id="@+id/btnSet"` and `android:id="@id/btnSet"`in android XML?

when to use that plus, when not? it would be great with a good explanation.

Comment: Other similer link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160954/what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-id?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**android:id="@+id/btnSet"** means you are adding a widget or view with the name **btnset** in your `R.java` file.

**android:id="@id/btnSet"**  means you are using or referring an already defined  widget or view with the name **btnset**

Answer (score 1):

`@id/btnSet` will try to use existing id `"btnSet"` while the `@+id/btnSet` will always create that ID. :) If you use `@id/btnSet` and the ID doesn't exist, you can encounter an exception.