# layout_below not working in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a Relative Layout with 3 children.

- 1st is ImageView cover.
- 2nd is ImageView avatar center in parent and
- 3rd is TextView app name below avatar and center horizontal.

As in theory it should work but my layout not place text below avatar. What's wrong with RelativeLayout?

P/S: I've tried both  `android:layout_below="@+id/logo2"` and  `android:layout_below="@id/logo2"` but still didn't work!

Thank you!

Here is my xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/android_apple"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo2"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/default_avatar"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="AAAAAAA"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the result:

[image: layout_below not working]

Answer (score 2):

Change the parent Relative Layout height to match parent. It will work.

Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/android_apple"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                          />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo2"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/default_avatar"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="AAAAAAA"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need layout height equal to ImageView cover height

Comment: You need to show your cover image to full page right ?

Comment: My cover image's height not full of Screen. And I want to use only one RelativeLayout with 3 children. Is that bug of RelativeLayout?

Comment: Check my updated answer.  may be it is an issue with RL. IDK

Comment: this assumes  Relative layout must be full height which is not true for my case at least so this answer is wrong

Answer (score -1):

try below code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/android_apple"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/default_avatar"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AAAAAAA"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/android_apple" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo2"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/logo2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo2"
        android:text="AAAAAAA"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="AAAAAAA"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

You are using layout_below="@+id/logo2". Use layout_below="@id/logo2", It will work.

Comment: those things are the same aren't they?

Comment: @Vryin, no they are not. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160954/what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-id)

Comment: I know that, and here I thought you meant different things. It still should work even with + or without.

Comment: If you give +, It takes that as new resource