# Error:(4, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_height' with value '@dimen/nav_header_height')

Tags: android, android-studio

here i attached my program.In this Program 2 
errors are there. I don't know how to clear those errors...

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light" >
```

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Comment: Post content_main.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android xml error: "No resource found that matches the given name" with RelativeLayout (@id/LinearLayout\_acc, @id/ProgressBar\_statusScreen)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668718/android-xml-error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-with-relative)

Comment: create a `dimen.xml` and create a resources `nav_header_height` and give the size in `dp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following line into "res/values/dimens.xml" file -

```
 <dimen name="nav_header_height">50dp</dimen>
```