# Error:(47, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/searchable')

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-manifest

I already looked at [Android xml error: "No resource found that matches the given name" with RelativeLayout (@id/LinearLayout_acc, @id/ProgressBar_statusScreen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668718/android-xml-error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-with-relative)

My code has been working without problems. But now I am trying to create a release APK and I am getting these gradle errors:

```
Error:(47, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/searchable').
Error:(81, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/syncadapter').
Error:(90, 35) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/authenticator').
```

Again I don't get these errors unless I am trying to create a release APK.

Answer (score 2):

I solve my own problem. For reasons I do not understand, the files were being created under `.../app/src/debug/res/xml`. I simply moved them to `/app/src/main/res/xml` and now it works.