# Why android:layout_alignLeft` is not supported here

Tags: android

I am a newcomer in android.I am trying to position the  "Amy" below the "kunal" and make the leftedge of "Amy" match the leftedge of "Kunal".But layout_alignleft is not supported here.Why?
I am a newcomer in android.I am trying to position the  "Amy" below the "kunal" and make the leftedge of "Amy" match the leftedge of "Kunal".But layout_alignleft is not supported here.Why?

```html
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lyla_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Lyla" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/me_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lyla_text_view"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Me" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/natalie_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/lyla_text_view"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Natalie" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jennie_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Jennie" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/omoju_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/jennie_text_view"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Omoju" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amy_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                            
        android:layout_below="@id/kunal_text_view"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/kunal_text_view"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Amy" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ben_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Ben" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kunal_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ben_text_view"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Kunal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kagure_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ben_text_view"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Kagure" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the parent layout?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/11669528/1457952

Comment: You should copy text, not posting images.

Comment: Thank you.But I want to make the left edge of "Amy" match the leftedge of the "kunal".So what could I do?

Comment: Thank you.But I want to make the left edge of "Amy" match the leftedge of the "kunal".So what could I do?

Comment: The parent layout is Relative layout

Comment: post your whole code

Answer (score 0):

Use parent layout as a `RelativeLayout` and put all TextViews inside `RelativeLayout` and then you can set TextViews using `layout_alignLeft` or `layout_alignRight`

Answer (score 0):

instead of layout_alignLeft use layout_toLeftOf like following code

```
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/kunal_text_view"
```

and also don't forget to add + in between @ and id like "@+id/"