# findViewById returns null

Tags: android, viewgroup, findviewbyid

I am building an Android app using a sliding menu like Facebook but the `ViewGroup` doesn't work properly. It works fine on my phone running 4.1 but when I tried to run my code on emulator running 2.3, `mContent = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.animation_layout_content);` this line always returns `null`; however, `mSidebar` returns the view correctly. I would really appreciate it if someone help with this problem. Thank you!

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_singlepane_empty);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE)) {
        setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE));
    }

    final String customTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE);
    setTitle(customTitle != null ? customTitle : getTitle());

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mFragment = onCreatePane();
        mFragment.setArguments(intentToFragmentArguments(getIntent()));
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.animation_layout_content, mFragment, "single_pane")
                .commit();
    } else {
        mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("single_pane");
    }

    mLayout = (AnimationLayout) findViewById(R.id.animation_layout);
    mLayout.setListener(this);
}


layout.activity_singlepane_empty
<com.oldroid.apps.planit.util.AnimationLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/animation_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<include layout="@layout/menu_sidebar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@id/animation_layout_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

```
 AnimationLayout
 @Override
public void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    mContent = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.animation_layout_content);
    mSidebar = findViewById(R.id.animation_layout_sidebar);

    if (mSidebar == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("no view id = animation_sidebar");
    }

    if (mContent == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("no view id = animation_content");
    }

    mOpenListener = new OpenListener(mSidebar, mContent);
    mCloseListener = new CloseListener(mSidebar, mContent);
}
```

Comment: animation_layout_content has been declared in ids.xml so this should not be a problem(it wouldn't work on 4.1 either if I didn't declare this.)

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
android:id="@id/animation_layout_content"
```

to:

```
android:id="@+id/animation_layout_content"
```

That is, unless you've added the ID elsewhere (in a resource `xml` file, or something). See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android) for details on `@id` vs `@+id`.

Comment: Eric, animation_layout_content is in ids.xml

Comment: Is `animation_layout_sidebar` declared in the same way?

Comment: Yes. that's why I don't get this error. mSidebar has a returned view object but mContent has null.

Comment: Well.. hmm. Try swapping the two IDs (put the content in the sidebar and the sidebar in the main pane) and see if it won't read the sidebar ID. This should at least help you narrow down the source of the issue...

Comment: Eric, I fixed it. I just copied the menu_sidebar.xml instead of using include. And it works like a charm. It's really weird I am really suspicious that this is a bug because the above code worked on ICS and JellyBean

Comment: Interesting. I figured it had something to do with the `include`, but didn't think *removing* it would help. You may want to post the answer you discovered for others to find.

Comment: I just did it. Thanks for your comments and answer :)