# android:layout_below with ImageView not working

Tags: java, android, layout, imageview

Do `android:layout_...`s work with `ImageView`s?  From the picture you can see that all 10 rows are on top of each other so that means that `q2Image` is not accepting the code `android:layout_below="@/q1Image"` for it to drop down a line and star the next row.

Am I just missing something or am I trying to do something that is impossible?

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="65"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/q1Image"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"  /> 

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/q1Question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q1Image" /> 

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/q1Answer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q1Question"  /> 

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/q1Verse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q1Answer"  /> 

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/q2Image"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/q1Image"  />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/q2Question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q2Image" /> 

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/q2Answer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q2Question"  /> 

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/q2Verse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q2Answer"  /> 

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />
//Above code is first 2 rows.  There are 10 rows total but I removed the code for rows 3-10 for this post.
```

[image]

Comment: for more information check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android

Comment: I read and tried both ways only to come with the same result with both.

Comment: Go to Graphical layout in eclipse and place it using mouse, instead writing the code...

Answer (score 1):

Try to put + between @ and id and everything must be ok

```
@+id

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- here the columns -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- here the columns -->
    </LinearLayout>
    .
    .

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Changed all instances to add the ````+```` but the result is the same.

Comment: Did you have a screen view for your issue? i think there is simpler way

Comment: What do you mean by a screen view?

Comment: design view. what the layout must look at

Comment: I don't have one but basically it is 10 rows with 4 columns each.  Column zero is a small picture (green check mark or red x) and then the last 3 columns are each a string.

Comment: Ok I will try to integrate it to a ````LinearLayout````.  I have been having a fit with this page.  ````TableLayout```` didn't work and now this one is not working for me.  Hopefully Linear will work.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing Id's like that not always working. Replace "@id" with "@+id" everywhere.
Example:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/q1Image"
```

Comment: Changed all instances to add the ````+```` but the result is the same.

Comment: I cleaned and rebuilt with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are accessing the ids in the code is correct. "@+id" is used to declare the id. All references to it following the declaration should be "@id". Are you having the same problems with the TextViews also? I think you should set the layout_below property for the TextViews as well. Because I can see text is also overlapped in your UI. eg.,

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/q2Question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below = "@id/q1Question"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/q2Image" />
```

RelativeLayout will not place a view below another unless you specify layout_below for it. Hence your TextViews appear overlapped.