# SimpleCursorAdapter will not populate my ListView, no error, just nothing happens

Tags: android, listview, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I tried to populate a `listview` from a cursor so I use this code:

```
Cursor curVal = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY order_cat ASC", null);

String[] inVal = new String[] { "nume_cat", "order_cat" };
int[] outVal = new int[] { R.id.title_cat, R.id.duration  };

SimpleCursorAdapter cadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, curVal, inVal, outVal);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
listView.setAdapter(cadapter); 
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

here are my XML`s:

**List_row.xml**

```
......................

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_cat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="FILL CAT NAME HERE"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title_cat"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="FILL DURATION HERE" />

 .....................
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/title_main"
        android:text="TITLE HERE"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
       android:padding="15dip"
      android:id="@+android:id/mainListView">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem :
When I run the app nothing happens and I can't see my listview. Eclipse don't return me any error or warning in logcat...

I tryed the easy method, using ArrayAdapter and all works ok, but I need to use cursoradapter because I need to have more than 1 textview on each list item.

Here is the working ArrayAdapter:

```
    ArrayList<String> catList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_row, R.id.title_cat, catList);
    Cursor curVal = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY order_cat ASC", null);
        if (curVal.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String data = curVal.getString(curVal.getColumnIndex("nume_cat"));
            listAdapter.add(data);
        } while (curVal.moveToNext());
    } 
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter); 
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Now lets exclude any questions:

**Yes**, my cursor contains an _id field.

**Yes**, I doublechecked my cursor and it has 20 rows.

```
System.out.println("Cursor adapter has " + cadapter.getCount() + " lines.");
```

prints "**Cursor adapter has 18 lines.**"

Is possible to be from:

```
    int[] outVal = new int[] { R.id.title_cat, R.id.duration  };

    and

    SimpleCursorAdapter cadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, curVal, inVal, outVal);

    NEED TO REPLACE WITH ?

    int[] outVal = new int[] { android.R.id.title_cat, android.R.id.duration  };

    and

    SimpleCursorAdapter cadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.list_row, curVal, inVal, outVal);
```

But how I define the ID as android.R.id.title_cat instead of R.id.title_cat?
If I put in my xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title_cat"
```

In my class file eclipse retuns me an error "**title_cat cannot be resolved or is not a field**"

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android

Answer (score 3):

I think you have problem at XMl. Check id of your listview.
`android:id="@+android:id/mainListView">`

Comment: I can`t do this because eclipse will not find my id anymore.

Comment: android:id="@+id/mainListView">  and is the same problem

Comment: Don't give this type of id anywhere `android:id="@+android:id/title_cat"`. Pls use like this for all your id in XML `android:id="@+id/title_cat"`

Answer (score 2):

Give id of listview as

```
android:id="@+android:id/list"
```

Then give

```
SimpleCursorAdapter cadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, curVal, inVal, outVal);
setListAdapter(cadapter);
```

instead of

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
listView.setAdapter(cadapter);
```

Also your class should extend ListActivity

Comment: The method setListAdapter(SimpleCursorAdapter) is undefined for the type Main

Comment: @catalin87 sorry u should extend listactivity instead of activity

Comment: ops, and how can I do this? because I already have " .... extends ActivityGroup   implements OnItemClickListener"

Comment: @catalin87 Is the ActivityGroup necessary?

Comment: hmm let me think how I get rid of ActivityGroup

Comment: @catalin87 : change as `String[] inVal ={ "nume_cat", "order_cat" };
int[] outVal =  { R.id.title_cat, R.id.duration  };
`

Comment: same problem, think I will go crazy :)

Comment: @Deepzz  What do you mean by: "Give id of listview as
android:id="@+android:id/list"?  That makes no sense if you are using findViewById(R.id.mainListView)