# error while implementing layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android .While implementing a Tab view in Android application I am getting an sort of error where I am not able to see the view/layout.

The error I am getting is `Could not create tab content because could not find view with id -1`

My `activity_main.xml` is as follows:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <!-- <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:fillViewport="true"
         android:scrollbars="none">    >> Close this layout used for scrolling tabs
-->
      <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#2184C6" />



     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />

     </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

The `error log` which I am getting is as follows:-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create tab content because could not find view with id -1
    at android.widget.TabHost$ViewIdContentStrategy.<init>(TabHost.java:593)
    at android.widget.TabHost$ViewIdContentStrategy.<init>(TabHost.java:584)
    at android.widget.TabHost$TabSpec.setContent(TabHost.java:441)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.setupTabHost(RenderSessionImpl.java:1041)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.postInflateProcess(RenderSessionImpl.java:892)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.postInflateProcess(RenderSessionImpl.java:967)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:293)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:318)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1638)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1389)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.reloadLayoutSwt(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1866)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.access$0(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1804)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener$1.run(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1798)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

My `java code` is as follows:-

```
package com.example.library;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FirstActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("Books")
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
 for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4E4E9C"));
        }
    }
        // Check screen orientation or screen rotate event here
        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            // Checks the orientation of the screen
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
                Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;

    }  


}
```

I am not able to go forward as I am not able to view the layout.

I read other questions on `Stackoverflow` but it is not helping me.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: can you post some of your java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign an ID for your `TextView`, it will work.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblTest"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all these,

```
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
```

try using this

```
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
```

Comment: Thread explaining the differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I think the error throwing because of your java class.

Your class name should extend from TabActivity then you will set layout like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActiviy{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activy_main);

}

}
```