# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignStart'

Tags: android, eclipse

I really don't know the reason behind this. 
In this block of code.

```
    <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progressBar"
      style="@android:style/Widget.Pbar"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignStart="@id/imgFrame"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:indeterminate="true" />
```

The error is always on this part. It states that `error: No resource identifier found
for attribute 'layout_alignStart' in package 'android'` .

This error sometimes disappear but then again appears. 
This was a big problem because i can't generate `R.java` because of the error on this part in `res`. So i tried commenting it out to be able to generate `R.java`. And then when i try to run the application, it will take too much time and then prompts an error encountered.
This project is an existing source which I imported/ added new project from existing source.

Comment: Replace @+id for @id

Comment: i've already did that. still no effect

Comment: Try Project  -> Clean

Comment: yup. done.. still nothing

Comment: @sftdev It will throw that, when you don't use `RelativeLayout`, Make sure that you parent layout is `RelativeLayout`

Comment: yes, the parentlayout is `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Please replace `layout_alignStart` with `layout_alignLeft`. They have the same effect on the view.

Comment: Not true: that'll mishandle RTL locales.

Answer (score 0):

Replace @+id for @id, see the differece [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)

Basically @+id is to generate a new entry at compile time to R.java file while @id is to reference an existing one. 
You are trying to align your item respect to another one that already exist.

`android:layout_alignStart="@id/imgFrame"`

Comment: yup, i know the difference between the two. I've just imported it and i've already noticed that one and already changed it. Still, nothing..

Answer (score 0):

`layout_alignStart` is defined only for [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 0):

just cut the line layout_alignStart="" the error will gone