# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignStart' in package 'android'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-manifest, android-menu

I have this project imported from another source and there were problems showing. From one of my layouts, it says "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignStart' in package 'android'" at:

```
<ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/imageFrame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    />
```

where imageFrame is an ID of a FrameLayout.

My project build target is API Level 17 and in my manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

In my menu xml file:

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
```

And note this was not literally "imported" but added through "Android Project from Existing Code"
I'm also using Eclipse for this project.

Comment: Try setting the `android:targetSdkVersion` to `17`, since the `android:layout_alignStart` attribute didn't exist before that.

Comment: Is this question not about the same problem described in this question (posted 30 minutes before)?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558958/error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-layout-alignstart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@+id/imageFrame can you try this one i hope it will work now

Comment: there is - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignStart

Comment: `layout_alignStart` is a reference to another resource. There's no reason to add the "+" character here. This is not a solution.

Comment: That solved it! Haven't read the line `Must be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name"`

Comment: grats i hope i helped you in any way