# Meaning of "No label views point to this text field" warning message

Tags: android, android-lint

What is the meaning of this warning?

> No label views point to this text field with an android:labelFor="@
>   id/@ id/editText1" attribute

Note that the double id (`@id/@id`) is a problem **with the error message text** and does not reflect the XML content (which is the correct syntax).

Comment: Read this post,it will be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android

Comment: We can ignore this by using `tools:ignore="labelFor"`

Answer (score 20):

The `labelFor` is an attribute for accessibility options. You assign this to a label so that if, on a form , user clicks a textedit field , android can know what to read (TalkBack) to user.

The id you assigned to it doesn't seem to be a valid one. why there are two `@id` in the id? Use ids like this: `@id/editText1`

Comment: Thanks. This is the only answer that actually explains what "labelFor" does and why we should add it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731137/difference-between-androidid-and-androidlabelfor contains additional information.

Answer (score 18):

I've had the same warning message. It disappeared, when I added a hint to my EditText

```
android:hint="Some explanation about the input..."
```

Comment: For anyone look for the eclipse character, here it is `…`.

Comment: @DavidChen Didn't you want to write "ellipsis" instead of "eclipse"?

Answer (score 13):

Although I am not familiar with the exact error you have posted. But it definitely sounds like you have done something wrong with the id in the `textView`. Use id like following in your `textView`.

```
android:id="@+id/editText1"
```

And if you want to set `labelFor` then use :

```
   android:labelFor="@+id/editText1"
```

Comment: this error will show in the XML if you simply drag a "Multiline Text" into a layout.

Comment: You should not have plus sign in the "labelFor" id. It should be: android:labelFor="@id/editText1" The plus sign is only used once to generate the id.

Comment: @wholladay yes, but that wont be problem here. + will add id if not exist. still thx for the suggestion

Comment: @wholladay It does matter if you try to reference an id before it is created. Either you add the +, either you re-organize your xml elements.

Answer (score 6):

It means that you probably should define a label for this edit text and link them using a labelFor inside that labels definition.

example code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:labelFor="@+id/my_editText" <!--the plus sign goes first in the code-->
    android:text="I'm a label" />

<EditText
    android:id="@id/my_editText" <!--no plus sign if not the first-->
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and it's not only for text views.

Answer (score 2):

Remove th first '@id/' , use like

> android:id="@+id/editText1"

which is the correct format. Keep going.. Best wishes.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by writing both attributes:

`android:id="@+id/editText1"
 android:labelFor="@+id/editText1"`

Answer (score 1):

Select the **editText**, go to **Properties**, then **Label for** and enter **@id/EditText1**

Comment: it makes no sense to me, but this actually worked !! Nice and ez way to get rid of a warning.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML looks correct and you're in a Graphical Layout mode then it's probably using a later version of the Android rendering layout that doesn't support EditText.

**In Eclipse and Android Studio there should be a green Android icon with what API version is rendering the layout.  Make sure you're using a non W or Wearable API as Android W APIs don't support the EditText element**.  (EditText is most likely not supported because virtual keyboard space is limited on those devices).

The rendered preview should support EditText in any API 4.X version without a trailing W.