# EditText warning in android app development

Tags: android

While declaring EditText in xml file, I was warned exactly as given below

> No label views point to this text field with an android:labelFor="@+id/@+id/start" attribute

EditText code is

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of "No label views point to this text field" warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896082/meaning-of-no-label-views-point-to-this-text-field-warning-message)

Answer (score 3):

I also had no idea what this error message was trying to inform me to do!

Thankfully I found an explanation: http://thecodeiscompiling.blogspot.com/2013/12/android-labelfor-waning-fix.html

> the warning is telling you the EditText field does not have a TextView that can be read to a user when accessibility is turned on, since you haven't specified one with the android:labelFor attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for this warning:
**No label views point to this text field with an android:labelFor="@+id/@+id/editText1" attribute**

When you drag and drop and **Text Fields** into **Graphical Layout** you get this above error .

The generated code looks like this:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
android:layout_marginTop="154dp"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName" >

<requestFocus />
```

Solution :
add this label **"android:labelFor="@+id/editText1"** as shown below .

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:labelFor="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
android:layout_marginTop="154dp"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textPersonName" >

<requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use id like following in your editText.

```
 android:id="@+id/editText1"
```

And then if you want to set labelFor then use

```
 android:labelFor="@id/editText1"
```

Comment: are you sure it is "android:labelFor="@id/editText1" and not "android:labelFor="@+id/editText1" ??

Answer (score 0):

**Use** `android:labelFor="@+id/start"` ***instead of*** `android:id="@+id/start"`.