# No label views point to this text field with an android:labelFor="@+id/@+id/" attribute

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` in my xml and I get this warning

> No label views point to this text field with an android:labelFor="@+id/@+id/et_password" attribute

I have searched in SO and I found these posts but unfortunately I don't find any answer that explains the reason of getting this warning.

1- [Meaning of "No label views point to this text field" warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16896082/2101822)

2- [EditText warning in android app development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231410/edittext-warning-in-android-app-development)

Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/ll_password"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_password"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0.3"
           android:text="@string/tv_password" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/et_password"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0.7"
           android:background="@color/background"
           android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
           android:inputType="textPassword"
           android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know why I'm getting this warning. 
What I have done so far:

1- I  tried changing my `EditText` id

2- Removing `TextView` in my layout

But warning still remain.
I just wondered because I have the same `LinearLayout` for my username without any warning.

Am I doing wrong? And what's the reason I'm getting this warning?

Comment: have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: But [Difference between android:id and android:labelFor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16896082/2101822) post clearly mentioned :`Specifies the id of a view for which this view serves as a label for accessibility purposes. For example, a TextView before an EditText in the UI usually specifies what infomation is contained in the EditText. Hence, the TextView is a label for the EditText.` so to remove warning add `android:labelFor="@+id/et_password" ` in `TextView`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK the link is Wrong and cant find this answer please correct the link

Comment: @Milad: Oh! Please see following [Difference between android:id and android:labelFor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731137/difference-between-androidid-and-androidlabelfor)

Comment: @NikoYuwono Yes of course. I've done that warning gone just for a few seconds and it came back :(

Comment: Why Down Vote. Am I doing wrong? or is there any problem with my question. please tell me so I can improve my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Three chance in my point of view**

1) It might be you have done something wrong with the id of the components.Use `id` like follows.

```
android:id="@+id/editText1"
```

2 ) You should not have plus sign in the `labelFor` id. It should be: `android:labelFor="@id/editText1"` The plus sign is only used once to generate the id.

3) This error will show in the XML if you simply drag a `Multiline Text` into a layout.

See [this](http://thecodeiscompiling.blogspot.in/2013/12/android-labelfor-waning-fix.html)

Comment: The link you've mentioned was very helpful. I really appreciate ;)
I just added android:labelFor="@+id/et_password" to my TextView and the warning gone. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

Just want to add some explanation to Anoop's answer. To solve the problem I just added this line to my `TextView`:

`android:labelFor="@id/et_password"`

It was not related to id of the EditText.

It was not related to + sign of id.

Here is the final xml code:

```
 <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/ll_password"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_password"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0.3"
           android:labelFor="@id/et_password"
           android:text="@string/tv_password" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/et_password"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0.7"
           android:background="@color/background"
           android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
           android:inputType="textPassword"
           android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's so strange, because this final code doesn't work. App couldn't be compiled because of error "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'labelFor' with value '@id/et_password')."

Comment: Oh! I just changed line `android:labelFor="@id/et_password"` to `android:labelFor="@+id/et_password"` in code, and it works fine only with **+** (plus).

Comment: I didn't need the `@+id` in `labelFor`. The above compiles just fine.