# Difference between android:id and android:labelFor?

Tags: android, xml-attribute, editbox

I wrote a simple layout which has an `EditText`, but it's showing the following warning message:

> “No label views point to this text field”

While searching I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16896135/2624806) and it solved that warning message, 
but did not get difference between both attributes `android:id` and `android:labelFor`. Any clarification?

Comment: [*this*](http://thecodeiscompiling.blogspot.com/2013/12/android-labelfor-waning-fix.html) might be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of "No label views point to this text field" warning message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896082/meaning-of-no-label-views-point-to-this-text-field-warning-message)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> **android:id**
>
> Supply an identifier name for this view, to later retrieve it with
>   `View.findViewById()` or `Activity.findViewById()`. This must be a
>   resource reference; typically you set this using the @+ syntax to
>   create a new ID resources. For example: android:id="@+id/my_id" which
>   allows you to later retrieve the view with `findViewById(R.id.my_id)`.
>
> Must be a reference to another resource, in the form
>   `"@[+][package:]type:name"` or to a theme attribute in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name".
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol id.

---

> **android:labelFor**
>
> > public static final int **labelFor**
> >
> > Specifies the id of a view for which this view serves as a label for
> >     accessibility purposes. For example, a TextView before an EditText in
> >     the UI usually specifies what infomation is contained in the EditText.
> >     Hence, the TextView is a label for the EditText.
> >
> > Must be an integer value, such as "100".
> >
> > This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
> >     "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form
> >     "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
> >
> > Constant Value: 16843718 (0x010103c6)

**UPDATE:**

*For example -*

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
     <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:labelFor="@+id/edit_item_name" 
    android:text="Item Name"/>
     <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_item_name" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="Item Name"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Reference: [android:id](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:id) and [android:labelFor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html).

Comment: in my case it is giving warning for EditText Field and when I update labelFor attribute in EditText, warning went. Here you update same attribute for TextView...I am still not clear in what reference it should be used.

Comment: Whats the advantage of setting labelfor?

Comment: @Psypher Accessibility purposes—without that, a screen reader has trouble knowing what's the label for an input field, and the blind can't "see" the label is next to a field.

Comment: It'd be good to explain the reason for the multiple `+`s, from reading the docs it sounds like they shouldn't be there. See comments below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731137/difference-between-androidid-and-androidlabelfor#comment65480318_32918913

Comment: For those who may not have the reputation to view deleted answers, I found this commend from a deleted answer very helpful: If the XML items get re-ordered, leaving out the "+" will fail. (And Android Studio likes to reorder the order when it doesn't matter). Adding it multiple times does no harm, and leaving it out is a formula for future headaches.

Comment: The layout_width of the TextView and the EditText would be better as wrap_content.

Answer (score 4):

`android:id` defines the ID of this view.

`android:labelFor` references the ID of another view.

Answer (score 2):

`android:id` Simply the view ID to (programmatically) access the view.

`android:labelFor` pops up sometimes in combination with the lint warning:

> Missing accessibility label: provide either a view with an
> 'android:labelFor' that references this view or provide an
> 'android:hint'

So, for example: If you have an `EditText` that does not describe itself, Android wonders if you might have some title or text (`TextView`) that might describes what the EditText is used for.
So referencing the id of the `TextView` basically gives you an idea what to put into the `EditText` with its text in the accessibility mode.

See:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#editable

Answer (score 0):

**in addition to all answers if u don't use xml files for apps this is a brief explanation what for serves VIEW ID :**

(btw in my opinion using xml sucks - my only xml file is manifest :D generated by gradle)

@IdRes - annotation for resource id

```
/** define resource id for view */
@IdRes 
int TEXT_VIEW_ID  = "111111";

/** create edit tex in code */
EditText myTextView = new EditText(Context);
/** set view id */
myTextView.setID(TEXT_VIEW_ID);
/** set layout params etc then attach or inflate as u wish to view hierarchy */    

/** use view id to find view */
EditText etFound = (EditText) View.findViewById(TEXT_VIEW_ID);
```

ps. ID is mandatory to preserve state of hierarchy view when Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is used - so if u create in code (VIEW / WIDGET / LAYOUT etc.) don't forget to set it.

Answer (score 0):

**android:labelFor**

> Use this attribute to indicate that a View should act as a content label for another View.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/email_subject_label"
        android:labelFor="@id/email_subject" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For more details: [Android Accessibility - How to provide content labels](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7158690?hl=en)