# Navigation Drawer that I created in Android Studio doesn't want to change layout when demanded

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am new to making apps and to coding. I am actually making an app for the playstore and if you help me, I am going to put your username in an info tab where I am going to put everyone that helped with the app!

First off, I changed the layout to a Relative Layout.

Then, I created a Navigation Drawer in Android Studio to use it like a menu in my application and when I tested my app it worked perfectly fine except that it wouldn't change the layout and it showed and stayed on one layout forever. Can someone please help?

I get a message warning which I don't understand it -

[image]

Here is what I wrote in my MainActivity:

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_fourth_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_fifth_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sixth_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_seventh_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_eighth_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new FirstFragment())
                    .commit();


        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I even included a screenshot with the layouts and the Fragments to see if I messed up there instead but I don't think that the problem is there:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28CsY.png)

If you cannot find any mistakes in my coding and need to check other files to find the error, I can show you whatever file you want!

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. As you can see in the *Suggested fix* section, it asks you to add the string resource in `strings.xml` file. Hardcoding strings is not a good idea. The second warning is related to [`EditText` labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896082/meaning-of-no-label-views-point-to-this-text-field-warning-message).

Answer (score 0):

These are not errors just warnings. You should always keep your strings in resources strings.xml file and use their keys in your layout files.

You don't have proper association of edit text. It should be as below

```
@+id/ediText
```