# Are Android View id supposed to be unique?

Tags: android

Ok so something  that I am confused with is whether Android ids need to be unique or not. Here is why the confusion arises:
Let's just say there is an `Activity` that has an `TextView` (android:id="text") and a `Button` (android:id="button"). The `Button` sets the text of the text view to a random text. So, to add a listener, I will retrieve **the** button as
`Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)` and then add listener to do the task.
Now, I can refer to this **same** TextView from a `DialogFragment`, a `Fragment` and what not with the same id `R.id.text` and all the changes will ever be applied to this text view without doubt.

In case of subclassing `BaseAdapter`, you need to override the `getView` where you do the inflating if necessary and if not, you make changes. Now, you retrieve the `Views` in almost the same way. Almost.
You do a `convertView.findViewById(..)`.

If all the views need to have a unique id, how does changing the content of `View` in the `getView` not result in haphazard behavior ?
I mean, all the views inflated have the same id as defined in layout.

*My understanding is that the ids are unique in the context of the view that inflated them. Since I am a beginner, I am asking for clarification*

#### Update after Ahmad's answer

So, what this means is I can not inflate two `Fragment` in an `Activity` by using the same layout. This will result in an exception. Both are inflated by the same `Activity`, hence belong to the same instance. The ids will conflict

Comment: There won't be an exception thrown. It is much too expensive for Android to go through and check that there are not conflicting ids. The only issue is if you search for a view using `findViewById()`, you could receive back *any* of the views with that id. So just as long as the ids are unique in the subtree of the views you are searching, you will be fine.

Comment: @AlexMDC Yes, exactly. You clarified it. I will get back any view if the ids are the same. :)

Comment: "the ids are unique in the context of the view that inflated them". Do you mean, they should be unique in the context of the Activity or View whose `findViewById()` method is being called, if you want to avoid ID collisions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) You may read

> **An ID need not be unique** throughout the entire tree, **but it should be** unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when possible).

It means there will be no exceptions if You use same id for all Your views but obviously layout will get useless then.

FindViewById works simply by traversing a tree until it finds first element with searched id and returns it (or null if doesn't find). If You had few elements with same id in tree You will always get same element, the one that is first in tree.

You may have plenty of fragments inflated with same layout just like you have ListView with each element having same layout, that is because inflater doesn't care about id values.
It simply reads XML file and create a tree with correct view objects nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

> You do a convertView.findViewById(..).
>
> If all the views need to have a unique id, how does changing the
>   content of View in the getView not result in haphazard behavior ?

This is because you create an instance of the view by inflating it. In this instance the ids need to be unique. Otherwise you will probably get a `ClassCastException` (If two different type of views share the same Id).

It would be impossible to maintain a `ListView` where every row would have to have unique identifiers for all its views.

> So, what this means is I can not inflate two Fragment in an Activity
>   by using the same layout. This will result in an exception. Both are
>   inflated by the same Activity, hence belong to the same instance. The
>   ids will conflic

No, fragments work in a different way. You have to return an inflated view in the fragments `onCreateView()` method. So each fragment has to inflate the view, which results in having 2 separate view objects.

Comment: So, my understanding was right. Each inflated `View` has its own set of ids :)

Comment: Yes kind of, the set of ids is the same, you just have different instances of each view that modify the view.

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using `android:id="text"`? You should use `android:id="@+id/text"` or `android:id="@id/text"` depending on what way you'll choose. Moreover, `getView` is relative to the item position on scrolled or not `ListView`

Comment: Yes, my bad there. Sorry :)

Comment: And yes, id is unique in specific area, ie. in `ListView` item when you are inflating a row id for `TextView` is different than id for `ImageView`. But for every row ids for `TextView` and `ImageView` are the same.

Comment: They are **different** views :)

Comment: I've tried to show it as simply as I can ;) When you use `@+id/`, the ids are collected and depending on which item you are refering using simply R.id.text the system choose this one which you wanted

Comment: What is the significance of the `"@+id/"` in the ID? could you link to documentation?

Comment: I think here is good explanation [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)