# Uniqueness of an ID for View object within a tree

Tags: android, object, view, unique, identifier

From Android developer [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html), a statement reads as under:

> An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be
>   unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often
>   be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when
>   possible).

Please help me understand, with an example, what is meant by 'part of the tree you are searching'?

Example, given following:

```
<AnOutterLayout>

  <Button android:id="@+id/my_button".../>

  <ASuitableInnerLayout>

    <Button android:id="@+id/my_button".../>

  </ASuitableInnerLayout>

</AnOutterLayout>
```

If I have:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

What will be search tree here?

Thanks!

Comment: Lint will warn you if you have views with same id in same layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "part of the tree you are searching" is typically the children of the [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) you're calling `findViewById` on.

In an `Activity`, the `findViewById` method is implemented like this ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java)):

```
public View findViewById(int id) {
    return getWindow().findViewById(id);
}
```

Ok, so how does a `Window` implement `findViewById` ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/Window.java))?

```
public View findViewById(int id) {
    return getDecorView().findViewById(id);
}
```

`getDecorView` returns a `View` - and all that the implementation of `View` does is return itself (if the views ID matches the one passed in), or null ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java)):

```
public final View findViewById(int id) {
    if (id < 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return findViewTraversal(id);
}

protected View findViewTraversal(int id) {
    if (id == mID) {
        return this;
    }
    return null;
}
```

It's much more interesting if we look at the implementation for a `ViewGroup` ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java)):

```
protected View findViewTraversal(int id) {
    if (id == mID) {
        return this;
    }

    final View[] where = mChildren;
    final int len = mChildrenCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        View v = where[i];

        if ((v.mPrivateFlags & PFLAG_IS_ROOT_NAMESPACE) == 0) {
            v = v.findViewById(id);

            if (v != null) {
                return v;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

So you see a `ViewGroup` traverses its children searching for the ID you pass in. I'm not certain of the order of `mChildren`, but I suspect it'll be in the order you add the views to the hierarchy (just checked - `addView(View child)` does add views to the end of the `mChildren` list, where as `addView(View child, int index)` adds the view at `index` position in the list).

So, for your example, which button was returned would depend on which `ViewGroup` you were calling `findViewById` on.

If you called `anOutterLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_button)`, you'd get the first button - as this is the first child element it comes across that contains that id.

If you called `anInnerLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_button)`, you'd get the second button.

However, if your layout file looked like this:

```
<AnOutterLayout>

  <ASuitableInnerLayout>

    <Button android:id="@+id/my_button".../>

  </ASuitableInnerLayout>

  <Button android:id="@+id/my_button".../>

</AnOutterLayout>
```

Then `anOutterLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_button)` would actually return the button *inside the inner layout* - as this view was added to the hierarchy earlier, and is therefore earlier in the list of children for that view.

**This assumes that views are added in the order they're present in the XML view hierarchy.**

Answer (score 0):

The button in the outter layer will be called first.

This post has a well-explained answer for your question

> [Are Android View id supposed to be unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067426/are-android-view-id-supposed-to-be-unique)

Comment: That's a good pointer. But, I want to, specifically, understand '...part...', as the document specifically points that. Otherwise, it's pretty clear that first match is selected. But, the confusion arises when the documentation mentions that you can search within part of the tree. So, I wonder how can you search within sub-tree? In other words, how to tell Android to search within a sub-tree?

Comment: That's an interesting thought, I have never thought about this. Up to now, I don't see any discussion on this topic. It is something Android will do it for you, and seems like it does not allow to customize the search.