# android first radiobutton remain checked in radiogroup

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button, radio-group

I'm working on my first Android Studio application and I have a problem with radio buttons that I can't solve out.
My application is a sort of multiple choice quiz and when I check the first radio button in the first radio group it remains checked even if I check another radio button of the same radio group, in this case I have two radio buttons checked at the same time as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

However, the other radio groups work perfectly. Radio buttons and groups are created programmatically as follows:

```
 LinearLayout layoutQuiz = findViewById(R.id.layoutQuiz);
 for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
      RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
      radioGroup.setId(i);
      TextView text = new TextView(this);
      text.setText(i + ") Question text?");
      layoutQuiz.addView(text);
            
      for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
           RadioButton answer = new RadioButton(this);
           answer.setId(j);
           answer.setText("answer nr" + j);
           radioGroup.addView(answer);
      }
      layoutQuiz.addView(radioGroup);

      radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
        //do something
      });
 }
```

How could I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a conflict between the IDs in the **LinearLayout**   when you use setId() check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18068110/7085389)

I tested your code and it worked with a higher Id for the RadioGroup

```
 LinearLayout layoutQuiz = findViewById(R.id.layoutQuiz);
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
            radioGroup.setId(i*1000); // i make chenge only on this line
            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            text.setText(i + ") Question text?");
            layoutQuiz.addView(text);

            for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
                RadioButton answer = new RadioButton(this);
                answer.setId(j);
                answer.setText("answer nr" + j*i);
                radioGroup.addView(answer);

            }
            layoutQuiz.addView(radioGroup);

            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
                //do something
            });
        }
            /*
            rest of your code
             */
```

### UPDATE

As @Mnih Ngo Suggests, use `View.generateViewId ()` to avoid ID conflicts when setting it programmatically

```
radioGroup.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

Comment: I believe this answer to be correct. The view-ID needs to be unique for the whole App. My guess is: Using the same ID for multiple RadioButtons made the program behave strangely. I'd suggest generating View-IDs with View.generateViewId() and getting the marked RadioButton through a different mechanism. But the view ID generation and getting-the-marked-button hint are for bigger apps than this exercise.

Comment: Yeah View.generateViewId() is best way but I've never worked with it. 1 question please if we use this method how can I get the id generated to use te View by the following

Comment: I left this part out, because your answer gives most of the details and would be a solution.
I break the question "looking for the answer through the ID" in 2 parts: 1) the ID needs to be associated with some data (answer and/or question).
2) In most programming languages one can associate a unique ID with with a value by using a map. E.g. a unique viewID with an answer value.
Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html and look for the appropriate Java version, if you're interested. Discuss it with me if you really are interested thru messages.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. I also found a way to do this with `View.setTag()`; if we want to use the view in the following code
by `ViewGroup.findViewWithTag ()` @Minh Ngo

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this solution, hope it will work.

```
LinearLayout layoutQuiz = findViewById(R.id.layoutQuiz);
 int selectedItem;

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
  radioGroup.setId(i);
  TextView text = new TextView(this);
  text.setText(i + ") Question text?");
  layoutQuiz.addView(text);
        
  for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
       RadioButton answer = new RadioButton(this);
       answer.setId(j);
       answer.setText("answer nr" + j);
      answer.setChecked(i == selectedItem); // Only select button with same index 
       radioGroup.addView(answer);
  }
  layoutQuiz.addView(radioGroup);

  radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
    //do something
    selectedItem=checkedId;//here set the id
  });
}
```