# How do I edit the content of a textview, which was originally being created in XML, from the .java source?

Tags: java, android, xml

In an XML file, a textview was being made, now I want to edit it's text property from the .java source file. I tried referring to its id, but eclipse wont recognize it; "cannot be resolved"

relevant part from XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="tb_01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

from the source:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String text = intent.getStringExtra(text);

    tb_01.setText(text);
```

also, could someone explain, what this does in an xml, within a editText tag:

```
android:id="@+id/edit_message"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide id like...

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tb_01"
                ^^^^^^^^^^
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

You can find difference between `@id` and `@+id/` at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android).

From java code reference it using this way..

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text = intent.getStringExtra(text);
TextView tb_01= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tb_01);
tb_01.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the Textview and set the text:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tb_01);

tv.setText("your text");
```

The

```
"@+id/edit_Message"
```

just creates a new resource `id`, which can be used to access that element programatically. Like "`findViewById()`" from above sample.

Answer (score 1):

The id should be like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tb_01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Then you will be able to get your TextView

yOU can get more information about these id's from the following link

[Difference between “@id/” and “@+id/” in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)

[R.id](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html)