# ClassCastException: AdView mistakenly get casted to an EditText

Tags: java, android, admob, android-edittext, classcastexception

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Talk" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stop_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stopBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/clear_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/speakerBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/speaker_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settingsBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_simple" />

    </RelativeLayout>


     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adTalk"
    android:layout_below="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:linksClickable="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

   <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adTalk"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        googleads:adSize="BANNER" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        googleads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Java class

```
private EditText textField;
private AdView addView;

textField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textField);

//Load ads
addView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adTalk);


AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addKeyword("android games");
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
addView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Ths generates the following error

```
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x.xxx/com.x.xxx.Talk}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.ads.AdView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.ads.AdView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at x.xxx.xxxx.Talk.onCreate(Talk.java:107)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-19 10:57:11.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     ... 11 more
```

The hard things to solve this issue is, the above error is not happening if the XML file is like below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Talk" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stop_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stopBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/clear_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/speakerBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/speaker_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settingsBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_simple" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
             >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

   <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adTalk"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        googleads:adSize="BANNER" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        googleads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxx"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why is this?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Try to clean the project and try again. Eclipse stuffs up ids from time to time.

Comment: Also, you should have only one `@+id` for each variable.

Comment: @Szymon: Yeah Eclipse. I didn't get your second comment

Comment: Check this for good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your layout to below. Make sure you have only one `@+id` for each variable you declare (the first time you use it).

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlPanelLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stopBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stop_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stopBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/clear_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/speakerBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/speaker_simple" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settingsBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/settings_simple" />

    </RelativeLayout>


     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adTalk"
    android:layout_below="@id/controlPanelLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:linksClickable="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

   <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@id/adTalk"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        googleads:adSize="BANNER" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        googleads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, let me check again