# android id in RelativeLayout

Tags: android

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/second_textview"
    android:layoutbelow="@id/first_textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="This is my first Android Application!" />

<Button  
    android:id="@+id/first_button"
    android:layoutbelow="@id/second_textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="And this is a clickable button!" />
```

I got error when tried to run.
There is a "red"  cross at the lines of:
- second

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

At following two places:

- `android:layoutbelow="@id/first_textview"`
- `android:layoutbelow="@id/second_textview"`

Change `layoutbelow` to `layout_below`. Note the use of **underscore:** `_`. If you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> while writing these attributes, eclipse will show you the options available(In case you use eclipse). This way you decrease the chances to such typo mistakes. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your textview and button line-

```
android:layoutbelow="@id/first_textview"
```

with this one-

```
android:layout_below="@+id/first_textview"
```

Use **"@+id"** in giving reference, not the **"@id"** here and you are missing the "_" in the layoutbelow attribute.

Comment: Actually Amit, he/she need not use `@+id` at that place. `+` is used only when you are declaring the `id` for the first time in the xml. All the other times one can refer to it as `@id`

Comment: @ShobhitPuri ok, then whats the difference between them?

Comment: ^[Difference between “@id/” and “@+id/” in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android) :)