# Cannot place a Spinner below ScrollView in Android XML

Tags: android, xml

I have a `ScrollView` that contains a `TextView`, and a `Spinner`. I'd like to place the `ScrollView` directly above the `Spinner`. My code is giving me an error when I try to run the project, however:

```
Error:(11, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/tense_spinner').
```

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.wsandhu.conjugation.LearnActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_above="@id/tense_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView android:text="Placeholder text"
    android:id="@+id/learn_textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ScrollView>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/tense_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea?

Comment: @Yurets no, I'm trying to place the Spinner outside of the ScrollView, below it. Not inside of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this..

replace this line

```
android:layout_above="@id/tense_spinner"
```

by this line

```
android:layout_above="@+id/tense_spinner"
```

also check this

[Difference between "@id/" and "@+id/" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)

**edit**

**OR** use linear layout instead

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.wsandhu.conjugation.LearnActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/learn_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Placeholder text" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/tense_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The first answer was a big help! Thank you!

Comment: thumbs up for the link to difference between "@id/" and "@+id/" . Good one