# Not able to set Onclicklistener on a editext present in a popup

Tags: android, android-edittext, popup, onclicklistener, android-popupwindow

I have a popup implemented inside an Activity,and i'm trying to add onclicklistener to it,but it shows an error "Trying to invoke virtual method on a null object reference",but i checked the id of the edittext,which is "date_from" in popupdashboard.xml,am i missing something,do i need to add a reference for popdashboard.xml somewhere ??

```
    public class DashboardActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
ImageView image;
    EditText datefrom,dateto;
    TextView amo_today,amo_yest,increase,percent;


    private PopupWindow active;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard2);
        datefrom = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date_from);
        datefrom.setOnClickListener(this);
      dateto = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date_to);
       dateto.setOnClickListener(this);
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you add your popcode in your activity

Comment: Could be because `date_from` is not in `activity_dashboard2` layout. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193552/null-pointer-exception-on-setonclicklistener

Comment: inflate the popupdashboard.xml to view and from which you get reference of edittext

Comment: @Nidhin it is being populated all right,but not right away,i'm looking for other eventlisteners,so i'm using it to populate when that event is called

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 that is the first example i saw,i couldn't figure out anything from it,because i'm implementing Onclick method through my dashboardactivity,so i'm inflating popup and everyhting else in OnClick method which was autogenerated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code contain setup for showing popup window

```
  active = new PopupWindow(ctx);
  inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  layout = R.layout.popupdashboard;
  contentView = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        datefrom = (EditText) contentView.findViewById(R.id.date_from);
  active.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        active.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  active.setContentView(contentView);
  active.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, position_x,
                position_y);
```

Comment: Your answer gave me an insight,i type casted layoutinflater,view and viewgroup and used the view inside a click event,and everything seems fine now,thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

If your **edit text is inside a popup window**, then you should get its view using popup context. You can do the same as follow :
Please note that, before you use **active** to find other view, you first to get its view using activity context.

```
// active = (PopupWindow)findViewById(R.id.active) // active is id of your popup in xml
datefrom = (EditText)active.findViewById(R.id.date_from);
dateto = (EditText)active.findViewById(R.id.date_to);
```

Comment: Should i define this in the Oncreate method ??

Comment: i type casted layoutinflater,view and viewgroup outside oncreate and used the view inside a click event,and everything seems fine now,thanks a lot for your help