# How Can I initialize my variables from another layout?

Tags: java, android

After much research, I have been unable to figure out how I can initialize my TextView in my java file in Android Studio. The TextView in question is located in a different layout file so I don't know the correct syntax to use. I think my question is similar to: [Null pointer Exception on .setOnClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193552/null-pointer-exception-on-setonclicklistener)
But the solution for him is not working for me.
Here is my troublesome code:

```
 Microsoft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Microsoft);
        Microsoft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
                TextView score = (TextView) 
score.findViewById(R.id.question2);
                (score).setText(0);

            }
        });
```

TheFindViewById part is the part I need.

FULL CODE VVVV

```
package org.flinthill.finalprojectv3;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button SuSe;
    Button DOS;
    Button B;
    Button BIOS;
    Button Microsoft;
    Button LenBosackandSandyLerner;
    Button HaskelDiklah;
    Button SteveWozniak;

    SuSe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SuSe);
    SuSe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            (score).setText(0);

        }
    });
    DOS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DOS);
    DOS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            (score).setText("0");

        }
    });

    B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B);
    B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            (score).setText("0");

        }
    });
    BIOS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BIOS);
    BIOS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            (score).setText("1");

            setContentView(R.layout.question2);

        }
    });

    //QUESTION 2

    Microsoft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Microsoft);
    Microsoft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            TextView score = (TextView) 
score.findViewById(R.id.question2);
            (score).setText(0);

        }
    });
    /*LenBosackandSandyLerner = (Button) 
findViewById(R.id.LenBosackandSandyLerner);
    LenBosackandSandyLerner.setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            (score).setText("2");

            setContentView(R.layout.question3);

        }
    });

    HaskelDiklah = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HaskelDiklah);
    HaskelDiklah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            (score).setText("0");

        }
    });
    SteveWozniak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SteveWozniak);
    SteveWozniak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            (score).setText("0");

        }
    });*/

}

}
```

XML CODE:

LAYOUT 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/android"
tools:context="org.flinthill.finalprojectv3.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/LUL"
    android:textColor="@color/LightGreen"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:text="Which is NOT an OS?"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SuSe"
    android:onClick="SuSeClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SuSe"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LUL"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/BIOS"
    android:onClick="BIOSClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BIOS"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SuSe"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/DOS"
    android:onClick="DOSClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DOS"
    android:layout_below="@+id/BIOS"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/B"
    android:onClick="BClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="B"
    android:layout_below="@+id/DOS"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="32dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LUL"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

LAYOUT 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/question2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/android"
tools:context="org.flinthill.finalprojectv3.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/question2text"
    android:textColor="@color/LightGreen"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:text="Who created Cisco"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Microsoft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Microsoft"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question2text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/LenBosackandSandyLerner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Len Bosack and Sandy Lerner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Microsoft"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/HaskelDiklah"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Haskel Diklah"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LenBosackandSandyLerner"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SteveWozniak"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Steve Wozniak"
    android:layout_below="@+id/HaskelDiklah"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="32dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/question2text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what you wanna achieve? set 0 to textview while clicking on button?

Comment: Well, where does `R.id.score` exist? Did you you add it to the exact same xml file as those buttons?

Comment: If you're getting a nullpointerexception on the button setOnClickListener, then you're using the wrong layout.

Comment: Yes I would like the TextView to be set to "0" when clicking the button, R.id.score exists in the xml file called "question2"... Holy crap... why did this get so many downvotes? :(

Comment: Please see about creating a [mcve] and add your xml and the rest of the Activity code

Comment: and you are inflating same layout question2 for this activity/fragment?  & Microsoft button also in question2 layout?

Comment: I am using one java file to code for two layouts basically. And yes, Microsoft button is in the layout "question2"

Comment: Updated post with full code and xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   //Change the name id in the xml file
   Button microsoftButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.microsoftButton);
   TextView scoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreTextView);

       microsoftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               // This was declared above so now you can use it. You can only set it to a String not to an Integer.
               scoreTextView.setText("0");

          }
       });
```

Comment: You have three options. 1. You inflate it using the inflator service. 2. You create a custom button with extends the standard Button class. 3. You can include external xml files into the activities xml  by using <include ....../>

Comment: I will try inflating it. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that after inflating you need to add it as well!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this unless your `TextView` is within the layout your `Activity`, `Fragment` or `Dialog` controls.

The `findViewById` method  looks for `Views` within the layout previously configured by the `setContentView(layout)` or the layout inflated in your `Fragment` or `Dialog`. If it does not find anything, your `TextView` will have a null reference.

Comment: The question is about the TextView, I believe, not the button

Comment: Are you sure there is no other way to do it? In the link above, it appears someone figured out how to do it... Even though it sill didn't work for me it apparently worked for him.

Comment: can you put your xml file here?

Comment: xml files were added to the original post