# ListView item overlapping TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have implemented a `ListView` in an `Activity`. I am having issue with layout. I have a `TextView` in the `Activity` and then, below to it, I need to display the `ListView` items. Both are filling correctly, but the first `ListView` item overlaps the `TextView` layout, and hence the `TextView` text and first `ListView` item text appear in the same line. I am putting the layout text below. Please let me know what layout property I am missing and should use to correct the issue.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.rrd.school.project.AllClasses" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/allclassess_institutename"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:textColor="#0404B4"
        android:background="#DF3A01"
        />
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/classlistview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/allclassess_institutename"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

listviewitem.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.rrd.school.project.ClassListItme" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/classid"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/classname"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        android:textColor="#0404B4"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the first layout you show is not complete, I mean, we need to know what's around the TextView/ListView to be able to help you

Comment: Try `android:layout_above="@+id/classlistview"` in your first xml on TextView

Comment: @Budius ... i have put the complete code as you suggested

Comment: @JoanColmenero  - i have tried that... that didn't help but caused to shut down my app

Answer (score 0):

check this link

[Difference between "@id/" and "@+id/" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)

and

replace this line in ur `listView`

```
android:layout_below="@id/allclassess_institutename"
```

by this

```
android:layout_below="@+id/allclassess_institutename"
```

**Edit:**

align ur `TextView` to `parentTop` and try ..

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/allclassess_institutename"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#DF3A01"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:textColor="#0404B4"
  android:textSize="10pt"
  android:visibility="visible" />

<ListView
  android:id="@+id/classlistview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/allclassess_institutename"
  android:fillViewport="true" />
```

Comment: Hello M S, it didn't work and i think it shoudn't as well. @+id is used to register a new id under resource and @id is to use a predeclared one. i have already declared id for ""@+id/allclassess_institutename"" in above TV so why to declare again ?

Comment: @M S Gadag , It didnt' work too.... i also read the docs and i cannot use "@android:id/allClasses_institute" . it didn't appear in the list as well. you have used "android:layout_below="@+id/allclassess_institutename"" in your code but i think its not correct as its to register a new id and not to refer it. i used excluding the ""+"" here

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout arranges the views based on "relations" (got it, relative, relations) between the views. It's a kinda of complex, but very powerful ViewGroup. But if all you need is to have one under the other, you can easily replace with LinearLayout, like following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.rrd.school.project.AllClasses" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/allclassess_institutename"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:textColor="#0404B4"
    android:background="#DF3A01" />
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/classlistview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tried replacing the relatvieLayout with Linearlayout but that didn't work. Also layout_below are the attributes which can be used in RelativeLayout only i guess!

Comment: `layout_below` was my bad, I should have removed. I edited the XML on my answer to remove it. That should work, LinearLayout, orientation vertical. It will put every view one under the other.

Comment: logically it should solve the problem but not sure why list view is still overlaping the textview... :( ... didn't work as well . in the list i am putting id and name both but hiding the id view using visibility:gone ... can it cause this issue ?

Comment: Also if i use android:layout_above="@+id/classlistview" in the textview and then use android:id="@id/classlistview" in the list view , the application shuts down abruptly where  as per the documentation it should work properly...