# @android:id is not recognized by eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my xml file I have below list view.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:divider="@color/blue"
    android:dividerHeight="2dip"
    android:background="@drawable/list_divider"
    >
</ListView>
```

And in my java class I try to access the view as follows

```
ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

I get a error for this saying "list cannot be resolved or is not a field". But if I change the id as `android:id="@+id/list"`

How can I access the view by using the id this way `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

Also whats the basic difference between two ways of defining ID. Thanks in advance

Comment: `@+id` is used to define a new `id` and `@android:id` is used to reference to an `id`.

Comment: Do like this : `ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

Comment: ADT is no longer supported, people ought to switch to Android Studio eventually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention your id like

android:id="@+id/list"

@+id/list will create a resource ID in your app (=your package) with the name "list" and give it a unique ID. In code, that would be R.id.list.

@android:id/list will use the ID "list" from the package android (which, in code, would be android.R.id.list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Activity extends ListActivity`, you can access it with the convenience method

```
ListView myListView = getListView();
```

otherwise you would access it with `android.R.id.list`

> Also whats the basic difference between two ways of defining ID

1. `@android:id` references built-in android `resources`
2. `@+id` is a user defined id and will add it to the `R.java` file to be accessed later with `@id`

[See this post about more on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

- Android resources id are referenced by `@android:id/list` in the xml
  and `android.R.id.list` in the Java code.
- User defined id are referenced by `@+id/list` in the xml and
  `R.id.list` in the Java code. The `+` implies that the resource id value will          be generated  at compile time.
- id define in resource files as `<item type="id" name="list" />` will
  be referenced as `@id/list` in the xml and `R.id.list` in the Java
  code.