# ID error at XML validation Android

Tags: android

I want to know what is the different of declaring a variable or id as

```
@android:id/
@+id/
```

When I set `@+id/tabhost` on Tabhost, it keep giving me error, but if I set `@android:id/`. it work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between "@id/" and "@+id/" in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@+id` creates a new ID. Android does not know this new ID, so the app crashes.

`@id` uses an existing ID from inside your app.

`@android/id` uses an existing ID from the Android framework. Android already knows this ID, it can access the corresponding `View` and the app will not crash.

Answer (score 1):

Resource ID in Android are specific to a your package.

@+id/name will create a resource ID in your package with the name "name" and give it a unique ID, you can also check that ID in R.java file. In code, you can use like R.id.name.

@android:id/name this will use the ID "name" from the package specified by android (in code you can use like android.R.id.name.)
@android:id/ is use to get id from existing packages.

And tabhost are specified in the android package that's why its giving error @+id/tabhost ,so you have to use @android:id/