# NullPointerException on TextView using setText()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview

I'm rather new to android programming, and am running into my old friend the `NullPointerException`...

I've been on it for quite a while now, but can't figure out what is wrong.

basicly gives me a `NullPointerException` when I try to call any `.setText()` methods, maybe someone sees what I'm doing wrong here...(though i tried to follow examples as close as possible)

```
public class lessonView extends Activity {

TextView adressOfLecture;
TextView lecturer;
TextView lesson;

Lecture lecture;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lesson_view);

    Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
    lecture = (Lecture) data.getParcelable("student");

    adressOfLecture = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lectureViewAdressLabel);
    lecturer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lectureViewLecturerLabel);
    lesson = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lectureViewTitle);

    updateLabels();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_lesson_view, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void updateLabels(){
    adressOfLecture.setText(lecture.getRoom());
    lecturer.setText(lecture.getTutor());
    lesson.setText(lecture.getName());
}

}
```

also, here's my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.coronarip7.app.stupla.lessonView">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="(ort)"
    android:id="@+id/lectureViewAdressLabel"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/lectureViewTitle"
    android:layout_marginRight="86dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="dozent"
    android:id="@+id/lectureViewLecturerLabel"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lectureViewTitle"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lectureViewAdressLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="27dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lectureViewTitle"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="test"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

and the logcat I'm getting:

```
04-25 01:23:51.058  12236-12236/com.coronarip7.app.stupla E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.coronarip7.app.stupla, PID: 12236
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.coronarip7.app.stupla/com.coronarip7.app.stupla.lessonView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.coronarip7.app.stupla.lessonView.updateLabels(lessonView.java:59)
        at com.coronarip7.app.stupla.lessonView.onCreate(lessonView.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

seriously, I am out of ideas on how to fix it...

Comment: Could you provide your 'updateLabels' method? That's what the logcat is pointing to but since you haven't provided it, nobody can really help you.

Comment: I think `lecture` is `null`, but I can't be certain.

Comment: What is on line 59 of lessonView.java?

Comment: @pbabcdefp it seems like lecture has the value of "dozent"

Comment: @Emmanuel I'm guessing it's the updateLabels() method. That's why I've asked him to post it.

Comment: It is a line inside of `updateLabels()` I just want to know which one.

Comment: must be `null` `lecture`

Comment: Probably `lecture` is null, add `if(lecture!=null){...}` in your `updateLabels()` and see if you still have the NPE

Comment: @MOS182 he has added the method, at the the bottom of the code he has posted. Well, it is showing for me

Comment: I think it has to be `lecture`. The `TextView` fields were all assigned in `onCreate`.

Comment: Not sure of android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lectureViewAdressLabel", it should be android:layout_alignTop="@id/lectureViewAdressLabel". You maybe reseting the value for R.id.lectureViewAdressLabel. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)

Comment: I agree with @Rami. You've defined lecturer and lesson, so I believe line 59 is `adressOfLecture.setText(lecture.getRoom());` which then points to line 31 which must be `lecture = (Lecture) data.getParcelable("student");` which is causing the issue because lecture isn't receiving a value.

Comment: That's irrelevant sanj. The problem is he is not receiving lecture. He needs to look at the code where the intent is fired I think.

Answer (score 0):

First check if you properly put the extra in the intent. Then I would use the following test in your onCreate method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("student")){
    lecture = (Lecture) intent.getParcelableExtra("student");
}
```

Then test if lecture is null like Rami wrote earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thanks for the suggestions, but I'll go the global route. I'll create a static version of my array (from which i wanted to pass an object via the Intent), and just pass an int[] array with the coordiantes and call it in the new view.

But thanks for the quick answers anyways!

(I'm new to stackoverflow, is there a way to mark a question as "solved", or "not-needed-to-be-solved-anymore"?)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use static objects in your code like arrays, objects, they have globally available, you should create intent and add your data into your intent like and call your activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent ();
intent.putExtra ("student",value);
```

start activity with intent
And in your 
lessonViewActivity check for intent like

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("student")){
    lecture = (Lecture) intent.getParcelableExtra("student"); 
if (lecture !=null){
updateLabels ();
}
}
```

Comment: well, thats what i did, and that didnt work. and why not go static? because this view should display different content depending on what object would be passed to it.