# What is id used for?

Tags: java, android

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/button01"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:text="Sample"
  />
```

In this code, 
what does

```
android:id="@+id/button01
```

mean?
And when do we use that id?

Comment: id is used to reference that widget to your java file and access it from java file.

Comment: It is an unique ID of the layout item. You can access this item with this ID. It works in the same way as ID works everywhere.

Comment: its usage is same as usage of html elements id when we use them in Script. its uniquely identify the elements..

Comment: If you want to use that textview in your activity u have to fetch it by taking textview object and using findviewbyid method will give you access of that textview

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android

Answer (score 3):

As said in [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id)

## ID

> Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely
>   identify the View within the tree. When the application is compiled,
>   this ID is referenced as an integer, but the ID is typically assigned
>   in the layout XML file as a string, in the id attribute. This is an
>   XML attribute common to all View objects (defined by the View class)
>   and you will use it very often. The syntax for an ID, inside an XML
>   tag is:

```
android:id="@+id/my_button"
```

> The at-symbol (@) at the beginning of the string indicates that the
>   XML parser should parse and expand the rest of the ID string and
>   identify it as an ID resource. The plus-symbol (+) means that this is
>   a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources
>   (in the R.java file). There are a number of other ID resources that
>   are offered by the Android framework.

Example in the same doc :

```
<Button android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_button_text"/>
```

Now you can uniquely identify this button with

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/button01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Sample"
/>
```

This means that the `TextView` has a unique ID: `button01` which can be used to access it in the application. To access it, we use:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button01);
```

Operations can then be performed on this `View`, e.g.

```
text.setText("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

A unique resource ID defined in XML. Using the name you provide in the  element, the Android developer tools create a unique integer in your project's R.java class, which you can use as an identifier for an application resources (for example, a View in your UI layout) or a unique integer for use in your application code (for example, as an ID for a dialog or a result code).

Ref:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id