# android app unfortunately has stopped

Tags: java, android, xml

I had tired to build an android application and I face a problem.
I post my java code, xml and error.
Can someone teach me why it happened and how to solve it? Thanks!

This is what the problem that I face...

```
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.onemap.activities, PID: 21798
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.onemap.activities/com.onemap.activities.OneMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.onemap.fragments.MainMenu.onCreateView(MainMenu.java:88)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1047)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1237)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1339)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2295)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:375)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1997)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.onemap.activities.OneMap.onCreate(OneMap.java:58)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
10-27 16:35:22.488 21798-21798/com.onemap.activities E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
```

Here is my java code and xml

**OneMap.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.onemap);
        AppUtilities.init(this);
        pomPref = getSharedPreferences(POM_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
        pomEditor = pomPref.edit();
        favDB = new FavouritesDBHandler(AppUtilities.getContext());
        this.mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mMapView);
        this.mMapView.setOnStatusChangedListener(OneMapStatusListener.getInstance());
        this.scrollView = (SlidingMenu) findViewById(R.id.mScrollView);
        View mainContent = this.scrollView.getMainContent();

        OnClickListener clickListener = getClickListener();
        OnLongClickListener longClickListener = getLongClickListener();
        mainContent.findViewById(R.id.mScreenToggle).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        JewelContainer jewelContainer = (JewelContainer) mainContent.findViewById(R.id.jewel_container);
        jewelContainer.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        jewelContainer.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);

        this.mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(getSingleTapListener());
        this.mMapView.setOnLongPressListener(getLongPressListener());
        this.mMapView.setCalloutClickListener(getClickListener());
        this.mMapView.getCallout().setMaxWidth(550);
    }
```

**MainMenu.java**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_main, container, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.arrowUp = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow_up);
        viewHolder.arrowDown = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow_down);

        ListView menuList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_list);
        menuList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        menuList.setOnScrollListener(this);
        menuList.setTag(viewHolder);

        MenuItem[] arrayMenuItem = new MenuItem[5];
        arrayMenuItem[0] = new MenuItem(0, "Services", R.mipmap.ic_menu_title_service);
        arrayMenuItem[1] = new MenuItem(1, getString(R.string.get_directions), R.mipmap.ic_directions);
        arrayMenuItem[2] = new MenuItem(2, getString(R.string.amenities), R.mipmap.ic_amenities);
        arrayMenuItem[3] = new MenuItem(3, "Others", R.mipmap.ic_menu_title_other);
        arrayMenuItem[4] = new MenuItem(4, getString(R.string.about), R.mipmap.ic_about);
        menuList.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(getActivity(), arrayMenuItem));

        return view;
    }
```

**onemap.xml**

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.onemap.widgets.MapView
        xmlns:callout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.onemap.activities"
        android:id="@id/mMapView"
        calloutStyle="@xml/callout_style"
        initExtent="29454.233386372267 39831.55546813806 30038.01821247406 40758.313879574656"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        callout:layout="@layout/callout" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.onemap.widgets.SlidingMenu
        xmlns:menu="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.onemap.activities"
        android:id="@id/mScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        menu:main_content="@id/mainContainer"
        menu:menu_content="@id/menuContainer"
        menu:menu_handle="@id/handle"
        menu:menu_marginRight="@dimen/menu_margin_r">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <fragment
                android:id="@id/menuContainer"
                class="com.onemap.fragments.MainMenu"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:tag="MainMenu"
                tools:layout="@layout/menu_main" />

            <include
                android:id="@id/mainContainer"
                layout="@layout/widgets" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.onemap.widgets.SlidingMenu>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**menu_main.xml**

```css
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/btnSearch"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.EditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/menu_item_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_edittext_search"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_search"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/menu_item_icon_padding"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:textColor="@color/selector_edittext_search_text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/listFooter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/menu_item_margin"
        android:gravity="right">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/iv_arrow_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/menu_item_icon_padding"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_arrow_up_disabled" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/iv_arrow_down"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/menu_item_icon_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/menu_item_icon_padding"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_arrow_down_enabled" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/menu_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/listFooter"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnSearch"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0.0dip"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0.0dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check the line `Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView`

Comment: post `menu_main.xml`

Comment: What is the line 88 of your _MainMenu_ class?

Comment: Do you have any textview in you xml? I think somewhere you are using textView without initializing it.

Comment: show your complete xml file

Comment: okay. I have re-upload the xml file

Comment: Line 88: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_main, container, false);

Comment: I have textview in my xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set @+id instead of @id.

```
android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
```

for more take it as a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)