# XML - android:layout_above Error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm building an App in Android Studio.

I've built a simple Splash Screen to launch it while my MainActivity is loading and to give my App a more professional look. This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_verde_mela"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/developerTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/developer"
        android:layout_above="@id/designerTextView"
        android:textColor="#9E9E9E"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/designerTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/designer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/splashscreen"
        android:textColor="#9E9E9E"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that when I try to build my App I get the following error which seems to be caused by `android:layout_above="@id/designerTextView"`:

**No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/designerTextView').**

I can't figure out what the problem is, since I've given the right id to my second TextView.

I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: move `developerTextView` after `designerTextView`

Comment: Not it, tried it myself. :D Had the same idea. I think you need to remove `android:orientation="vertical"` since Relative Layout does not have it. That's the only thing I can see at the moment. Btw copying these 2 TextView's in my Relative layout actually doesn't cause any errors.

Comment: As far as I can see, you're also missing `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` and `tools:context=".MainActivity"`

Comment: @Blackbelt moving developerTextView after designerTextView solved the problem. But why is that happening?

Comment: It is simple. Look for the difference between @id and @+id

Comment: @Blackbelt how do you explain it working for me in the opposite direction? **[I know the difference between @ id and @+id]**

Comment: @Vucko mostly you have declared the same id in another file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite easy to explain. You have text view which is referring `id` that was not defined before `@id/designerTextView`. This `id` is defined later with next code:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/designerTextView"
 ....
 />
```

To fix it place symbol `+` in first place where you refer this `id` and remove it in the second definition:

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/developerTextView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/designerTextView"
  .....
  />

  <TextView
        android:id="@id/designerTextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/splashscreen"
  .....
  />
```

Read more info here [Difference between "@id/" and "@+id/" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android)

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept answer if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

use this it is working I tested it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/designerTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="hai"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/splashscreen"
        android:textColor="#9E9E9E"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/developerTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"
        android:layout_above="@id/designerTextView"
        android:textColor="#9E9E9E"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```