# AndroidStudio always use @+id

Tags: android-studio, android-identifiers

I saw a lot of posts about the [Difference between "@id/" and "@+id/" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android), and correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that `@+id` is kind of a setter and `@id` is kind of a getter (broad simplification).

Playing around with Android Studio, it seems that it always uses `@+id`, even when the id is already set. If I understood correctly, this means that there are many duplicate id created.

And indeed, when I ctrl+click some `R.id.stuff`, Android Studio point me to all `@+Id`, not only to the `android:id=...`.

I could modify each one to `@id` when possible but it would be awfully tedious.

How can I tell Android Studio to only put a `+` to the fist instance of `@Id` ?