# Android id for the custom layout for SwitchPreferenceCompat

Tags: android, android-preferences, switchpreference

I have been trying to create custom layouts to **style fonts** for `Preference`(s) in a `PreferenceFragment`. For simple preferences with only title and a summary, I have been able to do so by mentioning a layout resources with android id(s) like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="70dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColour"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/secondaryTextColour"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This worked completely fine for preferences like `EditTextPreference` or a `ListPreference`. Now, I want to do the same for a `SwitchPreferenceCompat`. What I am unable to find is the`android:id` for the switch/toggle in `SwitchPreferenceCompat`. If I use the above mentioned layout, it works, but I do not see the switch any more. The layout that I have written for the purpose is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:minHeight="70dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="80"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColour"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/secondaryTextColour"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@android:id/??"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="20"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What is the `android:id`that I should switch for `SwitchCompat` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this id

```
android:id="@+id/switchWidget"
```

Comment: I see an option for `switch_widget` but it requires a minimum API level of 24. I am on a minimum of 19.

Comment: Are you using support-pref libs or not ?

Comment: No.. I will check that.

Comment: Yes, I am using `com.android.support:preference-v7:25.3.1`, if you mean the one?

Comment: Yeah ... It works.. I was using `android:id="@android:id/switchWidget` earlier. Any documentation pointing to this? Thanks :)

Comment: @Swapnil you can see the layout code inside the from External Libraries menu in Android Project

Comment: I'm not sure how this is an answer! @+id adds a new id, where is OP wants to use already defined id for Preferenences page!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android
it doesn't work for me.