# Android Studio 3.0 : canary 6 : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException inside Launching activity

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-studio-3.0

I update android-studio 3.0 from canary 5 to canary 6 and suddenly My app gives crash on KitKat(API 19) with below stacktrace.

The Main2Activity.java:10 line is the first line in my activity onCreate() method.

```
07-11 13:00:39.523 8913-8913/dcpl.com.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: dcpl.com.myapplication, PID: 8913
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dcpl.com.myapplication/dcpl.com.myapplication.Main2Activity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070058
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2318)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070058
      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1173)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:332)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:711)
      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
      at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:131)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:155)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:205)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
      at dcpl.com.myapplication.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:10)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Post your XML file

Comment: Happening for me too.. Same code works for Android 6, and 7.. Was working fine for Canary 5.

Comment: Same here. Our app crashes under API 19 Level. Downloaded again Canary 5 and our app is working again.  https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Comment: To create normal apk which can be launched outside of android studio just select menu Build > Build apk...

Comment: I have the same problem on Canary 9 with Kitkat (API19). but  "Android menu =>build =>generate signed apk " for release mode run ok.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Seems like the issue is related to Aapt 2.

Put

`android.enableAapt2=false`

In your `gradle.properties` file and it fixes the issue for me.

Comment: I have another problem, I'm unable to share the generated APK. It always fails wile installing via Fabric or Diawi. Installs only with USB debugging.This happens even with simple 'Hello World' project. So My question is , can't we build and share APK from Canary channel?

Comment: I don't think I have the same issue, I just tested on a project and can upload the APK to bitrise and install it on a phone.

Comment: Oh strange. I've tested it both at work place & home. It didn't work out :(

Comment: Above does not even build for me on 3.0 Canary 6. It starts giving errors like:
Information:Gradle tasks [:mobile:assembleDebug]
...\src\main\res\layout\profile_activity.xml
Error:(61, 39) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'labelFor' with value '@id/my_profile_first_name_edit').

Comment: @DroidLearner I stuck with same issue on Diawi, I share release build instead of debut and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Farrukh Najmi it is possible that you use resource (@id/my_profile_first_name_edit) before it get declares, try to add like this(@+id/my_profile_first_name_edit) instead.

Comment: Yes, my bet on that too nilesh, had the same issue and fixed it this way.

Comment: Yes It's works for me!! , One question, How you know this will work, is there any available in doc? can you please provide that link @Benoit thanks

Comment: @MaheshKavathiya check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android link

Comment: @nilesh Yes changing the '@id' to '@+id' fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: This solved my problem with abc_vector_test not being found. Thank you so much +1 on AS 3.0.0 Canary 6

Comment: what if it fails to find stuff such as @color/light_blue or @dimen/d2?

Comment: There is no resource in ur color resource file with name light_blue.

Comment: @nilesh there are these resource in another library module which is included as an API

Comment: @DroidLearner Can you check the manifest in the apk and see if the testOnly attribute is set to true in the application tag. If that's true, the apk can only be installed via adb. To generate an apk without the testOnly flag, use Build --> Generate Apk.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue.

put

**android.enableAapt2=false**

AAPT2. We are continuing to stabilize AAPT2 which enables incremental resource processing. If your build fails due to resource processing issue, please send us a bug report. To temporarily disable AAPT, set android.enableAapt2=false in your gradle.properties file.
Roboelectric is currently not compatible with AAPT2

follow the below link

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-5-is-now.html

Comment: in my case adding this line caused inflanting error. 
I've move back to canary5.
Also selector of items that are drawables not working on api19

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. To solve it, just update to **Android Studio 3.0 Canary 7**.

> Fixes:
>   [63623801](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63623801) ResourceNotFoundException running Kotlin project on API 16 AVD after upgrading to Canary 6

[Release notes](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/07/android-studio-30-canary-7-is-now.html)

Answer (score 2):

add this code in my project

`android.enableAapt2=false`

solved one of my issues:  with Android Studio 3.0 : canary 6, Gen a signed APK by default which can't parsered by "AXmlResourceParser.java"(axmlprinter2-2.0.jar)