# ResourceNotFoundException running Kotlin project on API 16 AVD after upgrading to Canary 6

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Build: 3.0 Canary 6, AI-171.4163606, 201707072113,

AI-171.4163606, JRE 1.8.0_152-release-884-b01x64 JetBrains s.r.o, OS Mac OS X(x86_64) v10.12.4 unknown, screens 1440x900, 1920x1080, 1080x1920; Retina

tl;dr steps to reproduce:

Create a fresh Android project with the Canary 6 Android Studio and run it against a Nexus 4 AVD at API level 16 (info below).  A ResourceNotFoundException will be thrown (stack trace below).  Running against a Nexus 5 AVD at API level 25 will run successfully with the expected results.

```
07-12 10:56:41.671 2865-2865/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bartonstanley.testforcanary6/com.bartonstanley.testforcanary6.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060052
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060052
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:755)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:88)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:202)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
    at com.bartonstanley.testforcanary6.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:9)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> ****** Stack trace from in-progress project ******

```
07-12 08:18:47.842 13073-13073/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bartonstanley.tododoingdone/com.bartonstanley.tododoingdone.views.root.RootActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070058
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070058
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:755)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:88)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:128)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:202)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
    at com.bartonstanley.tododoingdone.views.root.RootActivity.onCreate(RootActivity.kt:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> ***** Nexus 4 API level 16 emulator info ******

```
Emulator ADB serial number
    emulator-5554

Android version
    4.1 (Jelly Bean) - API 16 (Rev 5)

Emulator version
    26.1.2-4077558

Latest available emulator version
    26.1.2-4077558 (Stable update channel)

Android SDK tools version
    26.0.2

Host CPU Model
    2.5 GHz Intel Core i7

Device name
   hw.device.name: Nexus 4
```

> All of view details

```
Name: Nexus_4_API_16
CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
Path: /Users/bstanley/.android/avd/Nexus_4_API_16.avd
Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 16)
Skin: nexus_4
SD Card: 100M
hw.dPad: no
hw.lcd.height: 1280
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: Nexus 4
vm.heapSize: 80
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.lcd.width: 768
hw.gps: yes
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 16
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-16/google_apis/x86/
tag.id: google_apis
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: emulated
hw.mainKeys: no
AvdId: Nexus_4_API_16
hw.camera.front: emulated
hw.lcd.density: 320
avd.inidisplayname: Nexus 4 API 16
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.device.hash2: MD5:cd87b62509afda15361db744f4aa1ec0
hw.ramSize: 1536
hw.trackBall: no
PlayStore.enabled: false
hw.battery: yes
hw.cpu.ncore: 4
hw.sdCard: no
tag.display: Google APIs
runtime.network.latency: none
hw.keyboard: no
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

> ****** Gradle info ******
>
> Gradle version
>       4.1
>
> Android Plugin Version
>       3.0.0-alpha6
>
> Module Compile Sdk Version
>       API 26: Android 8.0 (O)
>
> Module Build Tools Version
>       25.0.3
>
> Android SDK Tools version
>       26.0.2

Comment: can you check update https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63623801

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was in **AAPT2** - please use the newest build tools (27.0.2 if I'm not mistaken) and it will contain that fix.
I Found a workaround here: [Android Studio 3.0 : canary 6 : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException inside Launching activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028246/android-studio-3-0-canary-6-android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception)

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63623801) they will re-open to examine.

Answer (score 0):

In `gradle.properties` file add

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

line this may help. check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45031035/6834114)