# bottom Textview is not set correctly based on my imageview android

Tags: android

[image: myoutputimage]

Hi My textview is not moved into next line,Even i set maxlenght,maxsize also,Need to set imageview width based height,Sorry for my poor english

Here is my xml what i tried,

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlTopview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/proimg"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/categoriesicon"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtcom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/proimg"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:maxEms="23"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Learn and Understanding \Node JS"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlack"
            android:textSize="18dp" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you need to change             android:text="Learn and Understanding \Node JS"
to             android:text="Learn and Understanding \n Node JS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<ImageView>` tag has a defined width of `200dp`. If what you want is for each card to be exactly 200dp wide, the image to fill the card, and the text below it to wrap if it's longer than 200dp, make these changes:

- Change your `RelativeLayout`'s width from `match_parent` to `200dp`
- Change your `ImageView`'s width from `200dp` to `match_parent`
- Change your `TextView`'s width from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`

Answer (score -1):

First of all please remove the `@+id` from the `TextView` it should be only `@id`. Then back to your problem you have three approaches, either to set the `ImageView` to full width like this

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rlTopview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/proimg"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="160dp"
android:background="@drawable/categoriesicon"
android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtcom"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/proimg"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:maxEms="23"
android:maxLines="2"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:singleLine="false"
android:text="The Complete Banking\nCourses"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlack"
android:textSize="18dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

or to set the `TextView` alignment to the `ImageView` like this

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/proimg"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="160dp"
android:background="@drawable/categoriesicon"
android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtcom"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/proimg"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:maxEms="23"
android:maxLines="2"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:singleLine="false"
android:text="The Complete Banking\nCourses"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlack"
android:textSize="18dp" />
```

third one will be like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtcom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/proimg"
    android:align_right="@id/proimg"
    android:align_left="@id/proimg"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="The Complete Banking\nCourses"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlack"
    android:textSize="18dp" />
```

Comment: You got the `@id` part wrong it is always `@+id`
Check out more info @ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_below

Comment: nope @+id means it will add id to the R.id but @id means its getting the value from there ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the insight :)