# Android: "@+id/" and "@+id/"

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android) thread I need to use `@+id/` for the first time to make resource be created.

But what if I forget that this resource was previously created and create it again with `@+id/`? I have some input and set `nextFocusDown` for the element that is still not declared.

```
<EditText 
...
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/myinput2"/>
```

200 lines below I create this element with `@+id` because I forgot that it's already declared.

```
<EditText 
...
android:id="@+id/myinput2"/>
```

It works like this but can it cause an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick definitions:

- `@+id/foo` means "use the id `foo`, and create it if it doesn't exist"
- `@id/foo` means "use the id `foo`" (which will be an error if the id `foo` doesn't exist)

Previously, there were reasons to prefer `@id` over `@+id` (the system could tell you if you tried to reference a view via an id that didn't exist), but now the system is smart enough that even writing `android:layout_below="@+id/idthatdoesntexistanywhere"` will be tagged as an error:

[image]

So just always use `@+id`.

Answer (score 1):

> It works like this but can it cause an issue?

No, it can't. Always use `@+id/`. By now, the Android build environment is smart enought to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you put two elements with the same `id` in the same `layout` file, it generates an IDE error (red underline) and you won't be able to compile.