# App crashes when adding an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

App crashes whenever I try to add an image in Android Studio 3. Please Help.

LOGCAT:

> 12-02 01:13:14.289 10530-10530/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main Process: com.divyam.demo2, PID: 10530 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.divyam.demo2/com.divyam.demo2.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML
>   file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) Caused
>   by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML
>   file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>   at com.divyam.demo2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0:
>   Error inflating class ImageView at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>   at com.divyam.demo2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   ID #0x7f060054 at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>   at com.divyam.demo2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)  }

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.divyam.demo2.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="344dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/download" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main Activity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }}
```

When I delete the ImageView the app works just fine.
I have tried everything resizing the image and reinstalling android studio.

Can anyone figure out the problem?

Comment: Something's wrong with the drawable-  it can't find it.  Is it a valid drawable file?

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: What happens when u add some other .jpg image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this :

```
  <ImageView
        ...
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/download" />
```

To this:

```
<ImageView
        ...
        android:src="@drawable/download" />
```

**UPDATE**

> Check the drawable directory, probably your drawable is in other
>   folders like drawable-large , drawable-xxhdpi , etc. then clean and
>   rebuild your project

Comment: could you put your  download.png file inside the  /drawable/ folder?

Comment: is a png file or xml file ? if it's xml put the content

Comment: It is a jpg file

Comment: check the directory, probably your drawable is in other folders like drawable-large  , drawable-xxhdpi , etc.  then clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Yes thank you. My photos were getting into drawable-v24. Now after changing it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Image resolution/dimension is the problem. Just check and change the resolution/dimension of the image file to a suitable size for mobile phones. I faced the same problem.

Comment: I did this tutorial:  https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-birthday-card-app-image and it keeps crashing. I checked multiple things. Then, read your post, and yes, the picture file is too large!

Answer (score 0):

You may messed up with [difference between "@+id" and "@id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android). Try to correct this line of that `ImageView` in your `activity_main.xml`

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
```

into

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/button2"
```

and retry.

Comment: What is the file type of image **download** you are using?

Comment: check my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Use **PNG** or SVG image as the source of your `imageView`. And **change** the below line:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/download"
```

**To**:

```
android:src="@drawable/download"
```

Comment: I used a png file and still the app is crashing

Comment: Did you try clean and building the project?

Comment: Thank you. My problem got resolved, images were going to drawable-v24 folder instead of drawable.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Glad you got help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image name has no spaces in between and starts with a small case letter.in additon save it in drawable folder instead of drawable(24) otherwise it reports error 90% of the time.

Answer (score -1):

Essentially you need to do a trial and eror by following below mentioned steps:

- Try **New Project** and add you **Image** first or whatever it may be and then run the emulator.
- If it is working, then start adding textView, buttons and other
  required objects to your activity and run your emulator at every
  instance you are adding items.
- If everything works fine, add code to your **Main activity** from old project and add all the changes.

It should Run fine. I actually tried this for one of my projects where I was facing a similar issue and it worked.