# Using @+id/ for the same ID several times

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

`@+id/`in an XML layout creates a new ID and `@id/` just references it. I noticed that it doesn't seem to make a difference if I use `@+id/` for the same ID several times.
So are there any downsides in just using `@+id/` all the time, even if I'm just referencing an existing ID?

Comment: *it doesn't seem to make a difference if I use @+id/ for the same ID several times* - it does if you use it more than once in the same layout tree

Comment: Can you provide some code samples and some more explanation please? Your question is much easier to answer that way..

Comment: You can use `@id/` for referring to id that has already been created . Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android. If not satisfied with answer provide MCVE.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yea you are right. I was playing around with the merge tag and placeholders, and there I could use it without a compiler warning

Answer (score 2):

This question provides a nice discussion on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025910/difference-between-id-and-id-in-android) matter. One of the comments by Levit mentions:

> there is also no negative runtime effect (possibly an unmeasurably small increase in compile time though)

So as far as I know the process of adding IDs to the R file happens during compile time, and there is no performance hit during runtime.